# Web2py - preventing uploaded file content from appearing in URL when using redirect() with request.vars

Tags: python, web2py

There is a nuisance when my web2Py page uploads a file through SQLFORM, and then redirects the user to the next page with:

```
redirect(URL('form2', vars=request.vars))
```

I guess that due to the 'vars' argument, all of the vars, including *the entire contents of the uploaded file*, appear as the arguments in the url of 'form2.' In other words, when the user is redirected, the url in the browser's url bar appears as [the_url]?file=[file contents],etc. This can obviously cause problems when a large enough file is uploaded.

What is the best way to prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
del request.vars.file
redirect(URL('form2', vars=request.vars))
```